# React-Router 1.0 alternative to Router.HistoryLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is alternative to Router.HistoryLocation in react-router 1.0 for removing hash from the URL?

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a separate [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package which react router is built on. It will use the push state version by default. You can read about using one or the other in [react-router history docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory) but I prefer to just use `createHistory`:

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={createHistory()}>{routes}</Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: By using above code i can only go to index route with the url **http://localhost/#/login** or **http://localhost/#/**. I am unable to go to other routes, router is redirecting to index route. I want to replace hash. My URL should be **http://localhost/login**.

Comment: Are you using the Link component to write your links? And on your server either redirecting requests to index.html or using Router.match?